# How to encrypt and decrypt a file with 3DES (Triple DES) in Java

Tags: java, encryption, 3des

This is what I have, but I can not decipher the file.
I do not find a logic that allows me to decipher.
I do not know if it is encrypting correctly, because I can not decipher it.

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
 import java.security.MessageDigest;
 import javax.crypto.Cipher;
 import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
 import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
 import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
 import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

 public class TestEncryptor {

     public static void main(String... args) {
         try {
             String KEY_STRING = "asdasdasd";
             byte[] key = getEnKey(KEY_STRING);
             String pFilePath = "D:\\fileTest.png";
             String pFilePathEncryp = "D:\\fileTestEncryp.png";
             byte[] archivoDecrypt = encryptFile(pFilePath, key);

             try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pFilePathEncryp)) {
                 fos.write(archivoDecrypt);
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }

     public static byte[] encryptFile(String pFilePath, byte[] pKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
         File file = new File(pFilePath);
         long length = file.length();
         InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

         // You cannot create an array using a long type.
         // It needs to be an int type.
         // Before converting to an int type, check
         // to ensure that file is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.
         if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
             // File is too large
         }

         // Create the byte array to hold the data
         byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

         // Read in the bytes
         int offset = 0;
         int numRead = 0;
         while (offset < bytes.length
                 && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
             offset += numRead;
         }

         // Close the input stream and return bytes
         is.close();

         // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
         if (offset < bytes.length) {

             throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
         }

         SecretKeyFactory lDESedeKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
         SecretKey kA = lDESedeKeyFactory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(pKey));

         IvParameterSpec lIVSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
         Cipher desedeCBCCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

         desedeCBCCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kA, lIVSpec);
 //        desedeCBCCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kA, lIVSpec);
         byte[] encrypted = desedeCBCCipher.doFinal(bytes);

         return encrypted;
     }

     private static byte[] getEnKey(String spKey) {
         byte[] desKey = null;
         try {
             byte[] desKey1 = md5(spKey);
             desKey = new byte[24];
             int i = 0;
             while (i < desKey1.length && i < 24) {
                 desKey[i] = desKey1[i];
                 i++;
             }
             if (i < 24) {
                 desKey[i] = 0;
                 i++;
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return desKey;
     }

     private static byte[] md5(String strSrc) {
         byte[] returnByte = null;
         try {
             MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
             returnByte = md5.digest(strSrc.getBytes("GBK"));
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return returnByte;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Decryption ligic is very similar, just use `desedeCBCCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kA, lIVSpec);`

Comment: Thanks for help me

Comment: You may have a look at my [code snippets](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) for encryption

Comment: CBC is insecure if the IV is ever reused (so an all zero IV is a bad idea). Your `getEncKey` is not a secure way of deriving a key from a password, use PBKDF2. Setting the last key of 3DES to all zeros (MD5 always output 16 bytes after all) is an *extremely* bad idea, as it may bring down the security of DES to 80 bits or even lower.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution, if someone else needs it.

```
    try {
        File inputFileNAme = new File(origen);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileNAme);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
        SecretKey secretKey = getKey(keyString);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher));
        System.out.println(objectInputStream.available());
        fileOutputStream.write((byte[]) objectInputStream.readObject());
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
        objectInputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers on StackOverflow. I don't know where you got `objectInputStream` for or why you need it to decrypt files. And pretty please follow a Java streaming tutorial and read e.g. about *try-with-resources*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion
I will keep it in mind in the future